# Efficient priority queue with multiple keys?

Tags: python, priority-queue

I have run into a problem which I am pretty certain somebody has allready encountered and solved, but I just can't find a solution.

I have a number of objects, each object has several keys. Say:

- (1, 2): A
- (3, 3): B
- (4, 4): C
- (5, 1): D

I need a "priority queue"-like data structure which lets me efficiently return objects by priority for each of the keys separately. For example, if I return them by the first key, I would get (A, B, C, D), and by the second key, I would get (D, A, B, C). However, I also need to be able to mix. For example, returning by the keys alternatively, starting with the first one, giving me (A, D, B, C). Obviously, popping an object by the first key should remove the second key.

A naive solution is resort the data when changing the lookup key, but it is too slow for my purposes. Another alternative is to use a heap and traverse the other heap for each object remove, but as far as I can tell that is also slow. Is there an algorithm for an efficient priority queue that lets me remove objects by multiple different keys?

If there is an implementation for python it would be really nice, but an algorithm would be a very good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to have a separate heap for each keys. When you remove the first element of one heap, you can't efficiently remove it from the other heaps, but you can "mark" it in some way (e.g. by mutating it, or by adding it to a `set` if it's hashable) so that it can be ignored if it eventually gets popped again somewhere else.

This may bloat your heaps a little bit as it will keep the useless values around, but I think it will still be much faster than removing and reheapifying.

Comment: That could certainly work! It's a bit hacky, but I think the complexity will be low enough for my purposes. Memory is cheap after all.